# Could not open port for debugger. Another process may be using the port

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

When I debug my app i get this error from MonoDevelop

> Could not open port for debugger. Another process may be using the port.

Any idea what is causing it and how to fix it? Thanks.

I've reinstalled everything and its still not working.

Doesn't look like anything is running on that port. I'm using monoDevleop 2.8.5 and iOS simulator 5.0

Comment: Is there anyway to change what port the debugger runs on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to  Monotouch came out and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer can vary depending on which version of MonoDevelop you're using **and** if you're trying to debug with the simulator or with a real iOS device.

First make sure nothing else is using the port 10000 on your Mac computer. Try the following command:

```
 lsof -i | grep LISTEN
```

That will tell you if anything else is using the port. If this is the case then exit the application using the port.

You can also use the USB port to debug (devices only). Go to the MonoDevelop preferences to enable this.

If this does not help then please edit your question and add the details (MonoDevelop version, device/simulator) and we'll try to guide you thru this.

Comment: Doesn't look like anything is running on that port. I'm using monoDevleop 2.8.5 and iOS simulator 5.0

Comment: Where is this USB option?  I can't find it in the MonoDevelop preferences.

Comment: @RalphB in MonoDevelop, select the **MonoDevelop** menu, **Preferences**, expand the **Debugger** item, select the **iPhone Debugger** item and use the (only) checkbox to select Wifi or USB debugging.

Comment: iPhone Debugger isn't an option under my Debugger item.  There's a General and Preferred tab, neither of them have that item.

Comment: You're not looking at the right place. There's a **Preferences** item (under the **MonoDevelop** menu). That will show you a dialog that has a treeview (left), first item is **Preferences**, last sub-item is **Debugger**, expand it (right arrow) will show the **iPhone Debugger** item, select it to get the checkbox (right pane)

Comment: Yeah I am looking there.  That's not what it looks like in 3.5 beta.  The last sub-item is "Unity" you expand that and see "Debugger".  If you click on debugger there is no checkbox for USB.  It's just "Launch Unity Automatically" and "Build Project in Monodevelop".

Comment: @poupou I have the same problem as Ralbh B.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem earlier today, and a simple OSX reboot made everything work again.

I tried what @poupou mentioned, but lsof didn't show any applications listening on port 10000.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using MonoDevelop 2.8.5 with the MonoTouch 5.0.4 trial, and it works as expected on my machine.

You can try changing the port, by editing the file `~/Library/Preferences/MonoDevelop-2.8/MonoDevelopProperties.xml` and changing the number in this line:

```
<Property key="MonoTouch.Debugger.Port" value="10000" />
```

to something else (like 12345 for instance). The log file (`~/Library/Logs/MonoDevelop-2.8/MonoDevelop.log` might also provide some clues if changing the port doesn't work.

Comment: I just searched my whole system and cant find that file to edit.The MonoDevelop-2.8/ folder doesnt exist...

Comment: That directory should exist, are you sure you have MonoDevelop 2.8 properly installed? Maybe try to reinstall MonoDevelop?

Comment: Is there a specific way to install it besides just dragging it into the applications folder?

Comment: No, dragging it into the applications folder should be it. In any case it's very strange that you don't have that folder. Do you have any MonoDevelop-* folders at all in /User/<you>/Library/Preferences/?

Comment: Not that i can see. Is the fact that I'm running Lion have anything to do with it?

Comment: No, you should have that directory in all OSX versions. Do you have this file: ~/Library/Logs/MonoDevelop-2.8/MonoDevelop.log? Can you pastebin it if you have it?

Comment: Deekor.  Running Lion the os now hides your user's library... you need to show the library by navigating using Finder's go to folder method or by using terminal entering: cd ~/Library then typing open ./